# return jsonp instead of json

Tags: php, json

I slowly implement jsonp compared to json as I read jsonp approach is safer, it prevent CORS. So in my server side how should the jsonp look like?

What I did for json is just

```
$arr = array();
$arr[] = {'a'=>'apple','b'=>'ballon'}

json_encode($arr);
```

what if it's for jsonp?

Comment: Use CORS instead of jsonp

Answer (score 3):

JSONP doesn't "prevent CORS", JSONP is a workaround to enable GET requests from third-party domains by explicitly requiring the server to cooperate with the Javascript. The way that works is that the requesting Javascript passes along the name of a callback function it would like to be executed. The server then cooperates by wrapping its response in this callback function. When this response returns to the browser as embedded code, the callback is executed with the data from the server.

If the request gives the callback name `foo`, the response should look like:

```
foo({"a": "apple", ...});
```

So:

```
printf('%s(%s);', $_GET['callback'], json_encode($arr));
```

Comment: so jsonp is still not safe? so far for json I wrote header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With"); in my server side, do I need these for jsonp too?

Comment: Define "safe". "Safe" for what?

Comment: CORS should ultimately supersede JSONP; JSONP is a workaround for same-origin policy which does not require additional technology. CORS must be specifically supported by the browser, JSONP is just using existing Javascript functionality. Yet it does it in a way that is still safe, because it requires the server's explicit support. That's not to say JSONP is impervious; start here for example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#Security_concerns